# how to recover an extjs4 store?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Model:

```
Ext.define('Voting', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    hasMany: [
        {model: 'VotingQuestion', name: 'questions'}
    ]
}
```

and:

```
grid.bindStore(voting.questions())
```

then use RowEditing to add/edit/delete/resort the grid

after this, If I click a cancel button, **is there any easy way to recover the 'questions' to init status (except reload store from server)?**

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?146721-how-to-recover-a-store&p=648024&viewfull=1#post648024

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how have you implemented the Row Editing functionality. If you have made it to persist the changes in real-time, I am afraid you will have to give a call to the server to bring it to initial state.

In case you save the state of few transactions at client side , then you can have something like UnDo/ReDo facility where user can undo or redo last transactions without having a server call. This is basically a design decision whether you want to have a network chit chat for every edit or you want to have a coarse grained data persistence that consists of multiple transactions.

You will have to be careful and watch out if the application is designed for high level of concurrent access than additional mechanism to handle data integrity have to be build.

You can have a look a [extjs-timeline](http://code.google.com/p/extjs-timeline/) whose goals state

> The Timeline project is an extension of the ExtJS interface library.
>   It's goals are simple:
>
> ```
> Provide a framework for undo/redo of user events.
> Be generic enough for widespread basic use.
> Be extensible enough for easy customization.
> Be free to everyone, for any purpose, personal or commercial.
> ```

EDIT : [Check this example,](http://recordform.extjs.eu/) this also has a delayed mechanism of persisting data.

Comment: extjs-timeline seems to base on extjs3.And the change of store is local, is there 'reject()' method for store?

Comment: couldn't understand...can you elaborate what you saying ...I have updated the answer with one more link check if that helps

Comment: sorry for my poor express. I mean is there any ext build-in method of Store,do the work just like Model.reject()

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not directly what you want, but have you tried

```
 grid.getStore().each(function(record){
      record.reject();
 })
```

Comment: I know reject.
but I wonder if store.each can got the deleted record?

Comment: Store.each gets the entire record, which holds meta data about whether it has been modified, what it is now, etc. To reject them all would probably be the "easy way" to restore the store to its initial state. If not that, I'm confused as to what you want.